# Is there a way to natively add a border around an image pasted into a VSTS/Azure DevOps work item?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

As the title says really; I've pasted an screenshot into a work item in Visual Studio Team Services (or Azure DevOps as it's now called), the image has a lot of text in it and so doesn't stand out as a screenshot without a border. I could open it up in a graphics package and edit it there but was hoping there might be a way to easily do this directly in the work item.

Thanks

Comment: Hey downvoter, would be nice if you could leave a comment as to why you thought this deserved a downvote... cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't such a built-in feature to add a border for an pasted image automatically in work item...

You have to edit the image and add border for it first, then attach/paste it into a work item...

Well, I have submitted a [user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/35452027-automatically-add-a-border-around-an-image-when-pa) for you to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future release...

Answer (score 2):

You can add a border using an HTML `img` tag and the `style` attribute.

To do this upload the image and insert it using the standard syntax and then retrieve the image URL.

Next replace the `![ALT](PATH)` markdown with a standard HTML `img`, for example:

```
<img alt="Whatever you want" src="
IMAGE_URL" style="border: solid 1px #CCC; margin: 5px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but have you tried wrapping in `kbd`?

```
<kbd>![alt-text](./your/image.png)</kbd>
```